# How to make sure we get a lossless image

Tags: c#, image, rotation, crop, lossless

I'm trying to write a code that gets an Image (PNG, JPG, BMP, ETC') crops and rotate the image.
I want to crop the image without losing information (no change in interpolation)
so i am using

```
        Bitmap target = new Bitmap(cropRect.Width, cropRect.Height);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(target))
        {
            g.DrawImage(img, new Rectangle(0, 0, target.Width, target.Height),
                             cropRect,
                             GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }
```

where target is the cropped image. img is the originial image and cropRect is the cropping rectangle i want to crop.
Because i maintain the image size (no zoom) there shouldn't be any information lost.

Afterwards i am rotating the image using

```
        target.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
```

because it is 90 degrees rotation - it should remain lossless.
Is that correct?
I couldn't find any documention on that subject, if anybody has a link i would appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DrawImageUnscaled`/`DrawImageUnscaledAndClipped` to absolutely make sure it doesn't do anything funky, although I doubt it would anyway in your case. And since it's 90 degree increments and/or a flip, `RotateFlip` should not degrade the image.

However, if you resave the image as a non-lossless format, you'll certainly lose some information.

Comment: (updated with some more information, I realize my initial answer left a bit out)

Comment: i'm saving it using ImageFormat.Bmp  - so it shouldn't lost information.
(if the original is Jpeg format - there is no point to lossless and if it's Png format - saving it as Bmp it shouldn't lose information)

Comment: Yeah either bmp or png will preserve all information (though not alpha in bmp, if you have that). I'd pick png over bmp all night long.